# Blur event for custom vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

**What I have**
A custom DropDown with a filter text input above. The DropDown can be opened independently from the filter text input.

**What I want** 
The intended behavior would be, that the dropdown closes when the filter input loses focus and also when I click with the mouse outside of the DropDown, so that the DropDown loses the focus.

**What I tried**

- Bind to the blur event on my root div element in the control, which doesn't fire at all.
- I also couldn't find anything about internal component methods which I could override.

**Code**

```
  <div @blur="onRootLostFocus">
    ...
  </div>

  ...
  ...
  ...

  onRootLostFocus() {
    console.log('LostFocus');
    this.deactivateSearchPanel();
    this.deactivateSelectionPanel();
  }
```

## Solution

I missed, that a div needs `tabindex="0"` to be focusable, this fixed my problem

Comment: Could you provide some code example?

Comment: @vchan Updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this?

Answer: You need to set `tabindex="0"` to make it focusable.

Here an custom dropdown how you could do it:

```js
Vue.component("dropdown", {
   props: ["value"],
   data(){
      return {
         open: false,
         options: ["BMW", "Fiat", "Citroen", "Audi", "Tesla"]
      }
   },
   methods: {
      toggleDropdown() {
         this.open = !this.open;
      },
      closeDropdown(){
         this.open = false;
      },
      selectOption(option) {
         this.$emit("input", option);
      }
   },
   template: `<div class="dropdown">
   <div @blur="closeDropdown" tabindex="0" ref="dropdown" @click="toggleDropdown" class="select">
   {{ value }}
   </div>
   <div class="options" :style="{'max-height': open ? '300px' : '0px'}">
      <div v-for="option in options" @mousedown="selectOption(option)" class="option">
         {{ option }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>`
})

new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
      selectedCar: "BMW"
   }
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
}

.select {
   height: 40px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background: green;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.option {
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   background: darkgreen;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover {
   background: green;
}
.options {
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: max-height 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"> <p>
   {{ selectedCar }}</p>
   <dropdown v-model="selectedCar" />
  
</div>
```

Comment: you dont have a component in there

Comment: @TheFool something like this? component with custom `v-model` on it

Comment: I think, he wants to propagate blur so i don't see why v-model should be required. Look here what I tried regarding his question but it didn't work. I want to $emit blur and listen to that on the parent. https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dew-v87py?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: This is what I want, but I don't see, why my blur event is not triggered on a div, while yours is getting fired.

Comment: @TheFool i see. divs need `tabindex="0"` to be focusable. i have said it in my answer aswell at the top

Comment: @TobiasW you need `tabindex="0"` on your div. i have even written it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Note there is also `tabindex="-1"` to make it not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation.

Also consider using a `<button>` instead because of accessibility concerns.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex